# External package suddenly throwing relative reference error when trying to build

Tags: vite

up until tuesday we had `['@uniswap/v3-sdk', '@uniswap/sdk-core']` in `build.rollupOptions.external` in our vite config. Although we're suddenly getting this error:

```bash
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@uniswap/v3-sdk". 
Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

Even thou the imports from that library are the same?